# Pseudocode format

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

Following shows, the written  Pseudocode,

```
BEGIN
String product_code
Input product_code
IF product_code.subString(1,1) == ‘A’ OR product_code.subString(1,1) == ‘U’
THEN Made in: United States of America
ELSE IF product_code.subString(1,1) == ‘J’
THEN Made in: Japan
ELSE IF product_code.subString(1,1) == ‘K’
THEN Made in: Korea
ELSE 
    ERROR
END IF
IF product_code.subString(2,1) == ‘5’ 
THEN Processor: Intel i5

ELSE IF product_code.subString(2,1) == ‘7’
THEN Processor: Intel i7
ELSE IF product_code.subString(2,1) == ‘9’
THEN Processor: Intel i9
ELSE 
    ERROR
END IF
IF product_code.subString(3,3) == ‘320’ 
THEN Capacity of hard disk: 320GB
ELSE IF product_code.subString(3,3) == ‘500
THEN Capacity of hard disk: 500GB
ELSE IF product_code.subString(3,3) == ‘1024’
THEN Capacity of hard disk: 1TB
ELSE 
    ERROR
END IF
IF product_code.subString(6,4) == ‘1024 
THEN Memory: 1 GB
ELSE IF product_code.subString(6,4) == ‘2048’
THEN Memory: 2 GB
ELSE IF product_code.subString(6,4) == ‘4096’
THEN Memory: 4 GB
ELSE 
    ERROR
END IF
END
```

That code is used to check the product code string and to find out what that string says
Can I know whether there is an error in that Pseudocode format?

Thank you

Comment: Are you looking for syntax errors or logical ones? Either way you need to tell us the pseudocode and/or product code formatting rules and syntax.

Comment: You do not output which error was detected.  Try something like `ERROR Incorrect value for country: product_code.subString(1,1)` and similar for the other possible errors.

Comment: A little bit of formatting would go a long ways towards helping to find any errors in your code.